# How to have a pop-up screen to warn that the time out of the session is over in shiro?

Tags: servlets, shiro

I have my project with shiro and I need when closing inactivity timeout, pops out pop up warning the user that the session will close. At the moment I have shiro with Servlet Container

Answer (score 0):

try using javascript to show a popup once timer expires here timeout stores timeout period and now run a timer and show a popup once timer expires. Demo code below but you have to customize it and it is not full code.

```
      var timeout=<%= currentUser.getSession().getTimeout() %>;
      var starttimer=timeout-60000; //+100000000;
      var timerstep=1;//In  minutes
      var alertbefore=5;//In minutes
      var logoutUrl="logout";//Url to logout
      var militimerstep=timerstep*60*1000;
      var sessionNoExpireMessage="Session will never expire!!!";

var sess_timer=window.setInterval(updateTimer,militimerstep);
    $("#timeout_timer").html(moment.duration(parseInt(starttimer,10)).humanize(true) + " remaining ");
    if(timeout<0)
    {
        clearInterval(sess_timer);
        $("#timeout").html(sessionNoExpireMessage+ " remaining ");
    }else{
        $("#timeout").html( moment.duration(parseInt(starttimer,10)).humanize() + " remaining");
    }
    function updateTimer(){
    console.log("In timer");
   // alert(timeout);
    if(timeout<0)
        {
            clearInterval(sess_timer);
            $("#timeout").html(sessionNoExpireMessage);
            return false;
        }

        starttimer = starttimer-militimerstep;
        $("#timeout").html(moment.duration(parseInt(starttimer,10)).humanize() + " remaining");
        $("#timeout_timer").html(moment.duration(parseInt(starttimer,10)).humanize(true));
        if(starttimer<=0){
            window.location.replace("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"+logoutUrl);
            window.location("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"+logoutUrl);
        }
        if(starttimer<alertbefore*60*1000){
            $("#session_alert").modal();
        }
    }

    function updateSessionInfo(){
         if(timeout<0)
        {

            return false;
        }
        ajaxCount--;
        resetajaxView();
        starttimer=timeout-60000;
        $("#timeout").html(moment.duration(parseInt(starttimer,10)).humanize() + " remaining");
        $("#timeout_timer").html(moment.duration(parseInt(starttimer,10)).humanize(true));
    }
```